# Merge files starting with the same filename similarity

Tags: powershell, pdf, merge, pdftk

I need to merge several PDF files that are located in one folder (**PDFsource**).

I have these 2 folders:

> **PDFsource**
> **PDFfinals**

I have multiple PDF files in one folder (**PDFsource**) with different file names. The PDFs that need to be combined together would have a partial file name in common; for example:

> **AU2925**-0.pdf
> **AU2925**-3.pdf
> **U8163**-0.pdf
> **U8163**-1.pdf
> **U8163**-2.pdf
> **U8163**-3.pdf
> **U8163**-4.pdf
> **U8299**-0.pdf
> **U8299**-4.pdf

I want to combine all the files in one file using the partial file name, **U8163** in this case.

I need to check all the file names in the folder (**PDFsource**), if 5 files starting with the same file name exist, combine them, save the final file in a separate folder (**PDFfinals**), and delete the source files (**U8163-0.pdf, U8163-1.pdf, U8163-2.pdf, U8163-3.pdf, U8163-4.pdf**).

I have **pdftk** and **PowerShell** installed on my PC.

Comment: All of Stack* has rules: ***SU Rules:*** [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask)  ***SO:Rules:*** [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: We all want things. Yet, SU/SO are not script writing services as many will tell you. Your need to show us your work. What have you tried? What did/did not work? Show your code. You have 4 times in your use case. DO, each of them one at a time, and note the results of each step to make sure you get what you expect, then move to the next, rinse and repeat, then put it together. There are many samples all over the web and the PowerShell help files to get you started.

Comment: Just curious, if you searched for anything to guide you? For example: ['PowerShell list pdf files with similar names'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+list+pdf+files+with+similar+names%27&t=h_&ia=web)   ---   ['PowerShell combine pdf files'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+combine+pdf+files%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I've been looking around for a while and trying different scripts here and there. After a few hours of sleep, I finally put all the pieces together from different sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I've been struggling with my brain for the past 2 days until I decided to post a question here. Yes, I've been looking all around the internet for a similar question and I found a few tips here and there. After a few hours of sleep, I finally made a script to work as I needed it.

This is the script:

```
$destinationDir = "destination folder"
$storageDir = "storage folder"
$sourceDir = "source of PDF files"
$filesByCommonBaseName = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir  -Filter "*.PDF" |Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '-')[0] }
foreach($entry in $filesByCommonBaseName){
    Write-Host "Operating on files starting with $($entry.Name)"
    if($entry.Count -eq 5){
        # we found five matches, move them!
        pdftk.exe $entry.Group CAT OUTPUT $destinationDir\$($entry.Name).pdf
        $entry.Group |Move-Item -Destination $storageDir -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you have something together. Take care. Keep on scripting.